# Using Restcomm SIP & Webrtc without the platform

Tags: android, webrtc, sip, jain-sip, restcomm

I am looking for a way to use SIP as signalling protocol for Webrtc in Android. I saw the RestComm open source code and I think it fits my needs. But I already have the infrastructure setup for TURN and SIP server. We use FreeSwitch for that purpose. My Question is, is it possible to use the restcomm android sdk with a infrastructure that is not from restcomm platform? Will it work?

Is there any other library or way that could be used for the purpose? Infrastructure is fixed and couldn't be changed. I need webrtc with SIP or SIP over websocket as the signalling method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restcomm Android SDK essentially offers VoIP functionality using SIP for signaling and WebRTC for media, so you shouldn't have any issues integrating with different server components.

Notice though that so far it's tested with Restcomm platform for the most part.

For more information on how to do that you can check [Quickstart Guide](http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/sdks/restcomm-client-android-sdk-quick-start.html) and also refer to the code for [Hello World](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/restcomm-helloworld) and [Olympus](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/restcomm-olympus) Apps

Comment: Will it work for mobiles which are present in SIP blocked countries / with carriers that block SIP?

Comment: Not sure the exact networking conditions you refer to, but in our latest version where TURN is improved for media and SIP over TLS is enabled we haven't had any issues both on Wifi and Cellular Data so far. So I'd say give it a shot ;)

Comment: I got it to work with my infrastructure. Thanks :) But I am behind a firewall which blocks the SIP. So I was asked to try SIP over Websocket as fallback since websockets do work inside our firewall. Because of the firewall, I get SipException when REGISTER is sent out. Works great in non-firewall networks.

Comment: If your server supports secure sip (i.e. sips either on 5061 or any custom port) you could enable it on the android SDK as well and see how it goes. I think it should work

Comment: Cool. Thanks will try it out. Marking as right answer as it did answer my question.